# sbt: No implicit for Append.Value[Seq[java.io.File], sbt.Def.Initialize[java.io.File]] found,

Tags: scala, sbt

I upgraded the sbt from `sbt-0.13.16` to `sbt-1.2.8` my following code is breaking

```
lazy val gruntDirectory = baseDirectory {
    _ / "public"
}

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets += gruntDirectory { _ / "node_modules"}
```

here is the error i am getting

```
/build.sbt:131: error: No implicit for Append.Value[Seq[java.io.File], sbt.Def.Initialize[java.io.File]] found,
  so sbt.Def.Initialize[java.io.File] cannot be appended to Seq[java.io.File]
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets += gruntDirectory { _ / "node_modules"}
                                       ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

how can i resolve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.value` to extract the value of a setting:

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets += baseDirectory.value / "public" / "node_modules"
```

If you want to define `gruntDirectory` for something else, you can do it like this:

```
lazy val gruntDirectory = Def.setting { baseDirectory.value / "public" }

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets += gruntDirectory.value / "node_modules"
```

Notice that you can use `.value` only on the right side of `:=`/`+=`/`++=`/`~=` assignments or inside `Def.{setting, task, taskDyn, inputTask, inputTaskDyn}`.